# How to properly apply weights to clothes?

Tags: armature, cloth-simulation, vertex-weights

After watching a few lessons on assigning clothes, I tried to do it myself, namely, I did the following:

- Removed all groups of vertices from the object (clothes);
- Added "data transfer" modifier, source set character body, selected -> vertex data -> vertex groups -> generate layer data, apply modifier;
- attach to character, alt P -> with empty groups;

The result turned out to be much better than joining with automatic generation, but still a lot of defects, below are the screenshots.

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]
[image: example 3]
Tell me how to apply weights correctly, what methods are better than what I described, maybe even some addons?

Comment: What mapping method did you use for the data transfer?  Recommend "nearest face interpolated" for this.  However, you can expect some problems of this nature that may require manual cleanup.  The best solution here is to bake your body+unders meshes to the texture of a single, manifold mesh and weight that mesh, rather than trying to use these as two separate meshes.

Comment: closest face with interpolation is really better, thanks.